# Can graphviz constrain the graph to a certain width?

Tags: python, graphviz

I'm using graphviz from python to plot japanese kanjis and their relationships. I'm exporting the output as a svg and using sfdp as a render engine. 
The output is roughly square (3000x3000). I was wondering if there was any way to specify a constraint so that the output is more like a vertical rectangle (for instance 5000x1000) than a square. 
It seems that the size parameters mostly work on the scale of the resulting image, and not on the positioning of the nodes themselves. But I have a lot of different connexe components so it should be easy to move them around.
Is what I'm trying to do impossible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`sfdp`, because it uses a spring model, tends to produce square graphs.  However, if you use `dot` you have the added attributes like `rank` and `rankdir` to shape your graph more to your wishes.

You can refer to [Node, Edge and Graph Attributes](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html) to see which attributes sfdp supports.

Comment: Thanks a lot! dot produces a very horizontal graph for this case, so I'm not sure I can make it work, but I'll keep trying!

Comment: To make the graph more vertical, use something like `rankdir="TB"` on the graph, and make sure each node has a different rank.

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with the [`ratio`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:ratio) attribute:

> ...
>
> If ratio is numeric, it is taken as the desired aspect ratio. Then, if the actual aspect ratio is less than the desired ratio, the drawing height is scaled up to achieve the desired ratio; if the actual ratio is greater than that desired ratio, the drawing width is scaled up.

So if the original graph was like this:

[image]

Adding the `graph [ratio="1.5"]` attribute will make it look like this:

[image]

UPD: also notice how the `ratio` attribute works in pair with `size` attribute, maybe the combination will be best for you. Detailed explanation in the ratio docs over the link I've posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I've tried playing around with ratio, but it seems completely ignored, and size seems to affect only the scaling of the final output. I believe it's probably a problem of support of the python library :s I've tried sfdp and neato, but it seems not to matter. This is probably as good as it gets with my library :s sorry!